# Running sphinx with nbsphinx

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

I'm just getting started with sphinx, and sucessfully built html pages from .rst files with the command

```
$ sphinx-build -b html source build
```

Since my goal is to create pages from Jupyter notebooks, I would like to work with `nbsphinx`. However, if I try to run mentioned command after adding `nbsphinx` to the extension of conf.py, I get following error message

```
Could not import extension nbsphinx (exception: No module named 'sphinx.transforms.post_transforms')
```

I *have* installed nbsphinx, as `conda list` shows

```
(dummy)  C:\Users\rata\someproject conda list

...
nbsphinx                  0.4.3                      py_0    conda-forge
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I encountered this error on a new computer... `pip install nbsphinx` solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I the issue was with the `sphinx` version. I was using version 1.5.1, after updating to 2.2.0 everything worked fine!

Comment: I am on sphinx version 4.3.0 and the problem is still there